# After a long time your friend has messaged you; how do we sarcastically respond to it?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

After a long time your friend has messaged you. How do you sarcastically respond him/her?

In my opinion, I may say, *"Now only you remembered me. what are you doing these days?"*

Comment: There could be 100 responses.

Comment: I need to say her in proper english.only now you remembered me.

Comment: In that case, a sarcastic way of telling him/er is, *Ah, you still remember me!* :)

Comment: yes .u are correct!

Comment: Oh, so you ***do*** remember me.

Comment: "What took you so long?"

Comment: "Who is this?" always works wonders! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one way you can respond. but here is what I'd prefer.

> Ah, you still remember me?

This conveys many things including -he/she called you after so long time; it seems that he/she completely forgot you and so on!

Answer (score 3):

A few idioms off the top of my head...

"It's been a while"
"It's been a long time"
"Long time no see" (a colloquialism)

Your suggestion:
"What are you doing these days" sounds pretty correct, as would be "How have you been?"
"Now only you remembered me" -- this sounds awkward, but I would interpret it as "You're only responding to me now?" or "You're just now getting back to me?" or "Took you long enough", and that would be a bit rude, but I suppose valid if you wanted to convey impatience or dissatisfaction. You could also use tone to say it jokingly.